# ssh keys on Rstudio connect server

Tags: r, scp, rcurl, rstudio-server, rsconnect

I am using scp (RCurl library) to transfer a filer from remote server to local directory. I have created a ssh key pair and it works fine in my local. However, I am now trying to deploy my app(The app transfers data from remote to local) to RStudio Connect server and it throws authentication failure error. How am I supposed to work with the ssh keypairs on RStudio connect?

```
scp("remote server", "path to file",
         keypasswd = "password",user="username", rsa = TRUE, 
         key = c("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub","~/.ssh/id_rsa"), binary = NA)
```

Thanks in advance.